# Clean up the URL

Tags: php, html

I currently have a url that looks something along the lines of

portfolio/index.php?page=home

My site runs all of the code through the index using simple PHP. In order to get it to work my index.php looks something like this.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <?php 
        // INCLUDING HEADER ON ALL PAGES
        include("pages/header.php");
    ?>

    <main> <!-- MAIN TAG !-->
    <?php 
        $pageLoaded = array('home', 'header' , 'get-in-touch' , 'work' , 'main'); // LIST ALL PAGES

        $page = ( isset($_GET['page']) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home';

        if ( in_array($page, $pageLoaded) ){
            include("pages/$page.php");
        } 

        else {
            include("pages/404.php");
        }
    ?>
    </main>

    <?php 
        // INCLUDING FOOTER ON ALL PAGES
        include("pages/footer.php");
    ?>
</div>
```

Then my header link does this in order to load the pages correctly:

```
<ul class="links">
    <li><a href="index.php?page=home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=work">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=get-in-touch">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there anyway that I could write my PHP to return a nicer looking URL?

Instead of the index.php?

Any advice to clean up my code would be greatly appreciated, as I am very new to PHP.

Comment: Google "url rewriting" or "pretty urls"

Comment: as for the "clean up my code" request, you should check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You need to use .htaccess for doing that. This is a basic requirement, so you can find it by simple google search.

Answer (score 2):

to answer using only PHP without rewriting modules, it might be pretty enough for you to simply omit the index page, use the page name as the array index, and check to see if it's set at all, but you'll still have a `?` in the URL:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<?php 
    // INCLUDING HEADER ON ALL PAGES
    include("pages/header.php");
?>

<main> <!-- MAIN TAG !-->
<?php 
    $pageLoaded = array('home', 'header' , 'get-in-touch' , 'work' , 'main'); // LIST ALL PAGES

    $get_keys = array_keys($_GET); // find all the pages in url, in case of multiple
    $matches = array_intersect($pageLoaded,$get_keys); // find matches

    if(!empty($matches)) $page = $matches[0];
    else $page = 'home';

    if ( in_array($page, $pageLoaded) ){ // now redundant, may want to play with other ways of serving 404
        include("pages/$page.php");
    } 

    else {
        include("pages/404.php");
    }
?>
</main>

<?php 
    // INCLUDING FOOTER ON ALL PAGES
    include("pages/footer.php");
?>
```

and now your header links can look like this:

```
<ul class="links">
  <li><a href="?home">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="?work">WORK</a></li>
  <li><a href="?get-in-touch">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your .htaccess right wher your index.php located

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

and just for a test, in index.php, try to do this,

```
<?php
  $page = ( isset($_GET['page']) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home';
  echo $page;
?>
```

and in your page.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="http://localhost/test/home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/test/work">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/test/get-in-touch">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

This must result, either on the three, home, work, or get-in-touch

hope this will help.

Comment: hmmm, I added that to my .htaccess. The link at the moment just rerwites to something along the lines of "pages/work" so where it should be "portfolio/pages/work" it drops that part.

Comment: That case you must create a router